# How do I "convert" a jobject class to a complex C++ type?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I have a Java class that matches a C++ class.  The java class is named `SDClass_JNI` and the C++ class is called `SDClass`. I pass the Java class as a `jobject` param to my JNI method.  In that JNI method, I want to then convert that `jobject` passed in as a param in my JNI method to the "matching" C++ method.  (e.g. `SDClass_JNI` -> `SDCLass`). How can I do this?

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and use [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/): It makes everything simple :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want an implicit conversion from java class to corresponding c++ class.

This is not possible, you should write code to handle the marshaling process.

Something like:

```
SNDClass toSND(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

    SNDClass result;

    jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/.../SDClass_JNI");
    checkException(env);
    //TODO release jclass object (env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);)(maybe use some sort of scoped smart pointer )

    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(mCls, "getField1", "()D");
    checkException(env);
    jdouble value = env->CallDoubleMethod(obj, mid);
    checkException(env);
    result.setField1(jdouble);
    .....
}

void checkException(JNIEnv *env)
{
    jthrowable exc = env->ExceptionOccurred();
    if (NULL == exc)
    {
        return;
    }
    //TODO decide how to handle
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Marius.  However then what's the point of JNI if I can't convert?  I have C++ objects within my C++ code that have methods that take C++ objects as params.  So I can't call those C++ methods from within my JNI code with parameters "passed in" from the JVM?

Comment: take a look at JNA (https://github.com/twall/jna#readme). It is a more high level library but I've only used JNI. About the purpose, we're using the c/c++ code, automating marshaling is to complex for the general case.

Comment: @Marius [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) doesn't do any marshalling and it works just fine! It's a bit hakish, but the point was to show that it is possible...